# error_reporting from script -> nginx+php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

i am using nginx+php-fpm. I am unable to set up error displaying via php-file like this:
`error_reporting(0);` or `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`

Working solution is via nginx.conf:
`fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 1000M \n post_max_size=1010M \n display_errors = On";`

But I need via php-script :-). Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use ini_set?

Comment: In php-fpm.conf? Because I need this for certain vhost only.

Comment: You can use ini_set in your vhost' scripts.

Comment: It's doesn't work, for me. See my original post. I can set `php_flag` in php-fpm.con when using pools, but I need in php-script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','on');
```

**PS:** `0` isn't a valid value for error reporting, there's [predefined constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) for that